# Does uprobe add a significant overhead for tracing?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf

I just started learning eBPF to trace function calls using `libbpf` project with `uprobe`. I started with the example `uprobe.c` and add high resolution clock to measure overheads added to the function call before and after uprobe is attached.

Here are useful sections of the code. All pieces are compiled with "-O2"

**uprobe_target.cpp**

```
int __attribute__ ((noinline)) uprobed_add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1, t2;
    printf("uprobed_add = %lu\n", &uprobed_add);
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto s = uprobed_add(i, i + 1);
        t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        printf("%ld,\t#%d\n", duration_cast<nanoseconds>(t2 - t1), s);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    }
}
```

**uprobe.bpf.c**

```
SEC("uprobe")
int BPF_KPROBE(uprobe_add, int a, int b)
{
    bpf_printk("uprobed_add ENTRY: a = %d, b = %d", a, b);
    return 0;
}

SEC("uretprobe")
int BPF_KRETPROBE(uretprobe_add, int ret)
{
    bpf_printk("uprobed_add EXIT: return = %d", ret);
    return 0;
}
```

**uprobe.c**

```
uprobe_offset = get_uprobe_offset(&uprobed_add_addr);
/* Attach tracepoint handler */
skel->links.uprobe_add = bpf_program__attach_uprobe(skel->progs.uprobe_add,
                        false /* not uretprobe */,
                        -1 /* self pid */,
                        "compiled_uprobe_target",
                        uprobe_offset);
skel->links.uretprobe_add = bpf_program__attach_uprobe(skel->progs.uretprobe_add,
                       true /* uretprobe */,
                       -1 /* any pid */,
                       "compiled_uprobe_target",
                       uprobe_offset);
    printf("Successfully started! Please run `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe` "
           "to see output of the BPF programs.\n");
```

The BPF hooks can be properly attached. We can find proper output from trace_pipe as `bpf_trace_printk: uprobed_add ENTRY: a = 184, b = 185`. However, before and after attaching the hook, the `uprobed_add` becomes 50x slower. E.g.,
*Before*

```
48,     #467
35,     #469
56,     #471
64,     #473
53,     #475
40,     #477
```

*After*

```
11573,  #19237
12242,  #19239
10274,  #19241
12566,  #19243
12360,  #19245
11727,  #19247
```

I initially consider it might be caused by `printk` function inside the hooks. However, commenting printing lines out doesn't change numbers overall. I also made another experiment using  `uprobe` from `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing`, which showed similar numbers before and after uprobe hook is attached.

```
echo 'p:enter_add /fsx/src/libbpf-bootstrap/examples/c/c.out:<uprobed_add_address>' >> /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/uprobe_events
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/uprobes/enter_add/enable
```

As long as I enable the tracing point, total time for each call immediately jump to 10000ns+.

Is it a true overhead for a call tracing using uprobe?

Comment: Yes, uprobe is known to impact performance. The reason for this is that your eBPF program lives in the kernel. When a uprobe is triggered, it must make a context switch from userspace to kernel space, similar to syscalls. 10k Nano seconds sounds like a lot, but is only 0.01 milliseconds, which is acceptable for most use cases

Comment: I think you should make this into an answer Dylan :-) I haven't found a good reference to corroborate it but it's still a useful answer.

Comment: If your kernel supports it and is not already enabled, you can enable the BPF JIT compiler (https://sysctl-explorer.net/net/core/bpf_jit_enable/) to make the BPF code itself faster and thus slightly reduce the overhead.